# Entity Framework never generates roles table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I am attempting to add role based identity to my ASP.NET 6 Core Web API project. I create my initial migration with Entity Framework. I then go to generate the roles table and it is not being generated correctly. I run this command.

```
dotnet ef migrations add add_role --project [PROJECT_NAME_HERE]
```

I suspect my problem is in my data context:

```
public class UsersContext : IdentityUserContext<User>
{
    public UsersContext()
    {
    }

    public UsersContext(DbContextOptions<UsersContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string connectionString = [CONNECTION_STRING_HERE];
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString, new MySqlServerVersion(new System.Version(8, 0, 22)));
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

My program.cs file could also be an issue.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.ConfigureResponseCaching();
builder.Services.ConfigureMapping();
builder.Services.ConfigureControllers();
builder.Services.ConfigureRepositoryManager();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication();
builder.Services.ConfigureIdentity();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ValidationFilterAttribute>();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.ConfigureJWT(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<UsersContext>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline. if
(app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(); }

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

`builder.Services.ConfigureIdentity()` is generated by this:

```
var builder = services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(o =>
    {
        o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        o.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UsersContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

So, when I run my EF migration command... this is the result:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "IdentityUserRole<Guid>",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    UserId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "char(36)", nullable: false, collation: "ascii_general_ci"),
                    RoleId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "char(36)", nullable: false, collation: "ascii_general_ci")
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_IdentityUserRole<Guid>", x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });
                })
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4");
}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "IdentityUserRole<Guid>");
}
```

I'm so confused.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change `public class UsersContext : IdentityUserContext<User>` to `public class UsersContext : IdentityDbContext<User>`